# Why extreme large value to 0 frequency fft (numpy.fft.fft method)

Tags: numpy, scipy, fft

I have a signal ts which has rougly mean 40 and applied fft on that with code

```
ts = array([25, 40, 30, 40, 29, 48, 36, 32, 34, 38, 15, 33, 40, 32, 41, 25, 37,49, 41, 35, 23, 22, 36, 44, 28, 36, 32, 37, 39, 51])
index = fftshift(fftfreq(len(ts)))
ft_ts =fftshift(fft(ts))
```

output

```
ft_ts = array([  -76.00000000 +8.34887715e-14j,   -57.72501110 +1.17054586e+01j,
       7.69492662 +9.79582336e+00j,   -29.11145618 -7.22493645e+00j,
      14.92140414 +4.58471353e+01j,   -26.00000000 -4.67653718e+01j,
     -39.61803399 -2.83601821e+01j,   -11.34044003 +8.66215368e+00j,
      23.68703939 +1.57391882e+01j,   -64.88854382 -2.44499549e+01j,
      50.00000000 -3.98371686e+01j,     4.09382150 -6.27663403e+00j,
     -37.38196601 -3.06708342e+01j,    35.97162964 +1.31929223e+01j,
      18.69662985 -2.20453671e+00j,  1048.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,
      18.69662985 +2.20453671e+00j,    35.97162964 -1.31929223e+01j,
     -37.38196601 +3.06708342e+01j,     4.09382150 +6.27663403e+00j,
      50.00000000 +3.98371686e+01j,   -64.88854382 +2.44499549e+01j,
      23.68703939 -1.57391882e+01j,   -11.34044003 -8.66215368e+00j,
     -39.61803399 +2.83601821e+01j,   -26.00000000 +4.67653718e+01j,
      14.92140414 -4.58471353e+01j,   -29.11145618 +7.22493645e+00j,
       7.69492662 -9.79582336e+00j,   -57.72501110 -1.17054586e+01j])
```

at 0 frequency ft_ts has value of 1048. Shouldn't that be the mean of my original signal ts which is 40 ? What happened here ?

Many thanks

Comment: try fft(np.ones(10))

Comment: @tom10 that seems to be correct resulting in array([ 10.+0.j,   0.+0.j,   0.+0.j,   0.+0.j,   0.+0.j,   0.+0.j, 0.+0.j,   0.+0.j,   0.+0.j,   0.+0.j])

Comment: Your array has 25 values in it? *wink* *wink*

Comment: @Jaime length is 30  why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FFT is not normalized, so the first term should be the sum, not the mean.

For example, see the definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition)

[image]

and you can see, that when `k=0`, the exponential term is `1`, and you'll just get the sum of `x_n`.

This is why the first item in `fft(np.ones(10))` is `10`, not `1`.  `1` is the mean (since it's an array of ones), and `10` is the sum.